# Dart any differences between with or without abstract keyword?

Tags: dart

Hi I just would like to know if there is any difference between giving abstract keyword or not like so.

```
// with
abstract class A {}

class B extends A {}

// without
class A {}

class B extends A {}
```

Should I give it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `abstract` you can omit implementations of methods and getters/setters

```
// with
abstract class A {
  int foo();
  String get bar;
  set baz(String value);
}

var a = A(); // error about instantiating abstract class

class B extends A {
  // error about missing implementations
}

var b = B(); // ok

// without
class A {
  int foo(); // error about missing implementation
  String get bar; // error about missing implementation
  set baz(String value); // error about missing implementation
}

class B extends A {}
```

Comment: One other difference is that you cannot create an instance of an abstract class, even if all its members are implemented. If the class is not intended to be instantiated, make it abstract.